# Css animation with display none doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a screen that includes a button on the left and a picture on the right and soon as I click the button CLICK, I want the image on the left to display none with animation. Later on, another box which was displayed none before, should display block.

```js
function calculate() {
  document.getElementById('body-mass-image').classList.add('body-mass-over');
  var el = document.getElementById('body-mass-result-box');
  if (el) {
    el.className += el.className ? '__show' : '__show';
  }
}
```

```css
.calculate__content__result { display: none; }
..calculate__content__result__show { display: block; }

#body-mass-image {
  transition: all 1s linear;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#body-mass-image.body-mass-over {
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="calorie__button__area">
      <button type="submit" class="button-secondary button__calculate" onclick="calculate()">CLICK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content" id="body-mass-image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBwAo9q5FtWQKO_hKSmgkKkrMZZtirYph9xg&usqp=CAU" alt="Weight Calculation Image"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content__result" id="body-mass-result-box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="result__box">
        <div class="title">Vücut Kitle End.:</div>
        <div class="calorie">33.9</div>
        <div class="title">Durum:</div>
        <div class="calorie">Şişman/Obez</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I display none the image and display block the result__box, but the thing is there i no animation.

Comment: display is not an animatable CSS property - use a transform of some sort (e.g. scale) or another animatabcle property like opacity or height.

Comment: Opacity and height dont work also because I want to replace image with div. So when I do that, for example image opacity to 0, it still stays there and the div (result__box) is being shown under

Comment: Please don't keep reposting the same question over and over again. It is expected that you take on board that this is not possible as it stands. Read the duplicate carefully (including all the answers) and one of them may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand you clearly, you're trying to make the image disappear slowly using display none on transition which for a very technical reason will never work.

Transition will work perfectly on opacity because opacity has value count down ranging from value 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 till 1.0, so it is possible that within the 1 second you gave, it will translate through those values... But display has no count down, it's either it display or it doesn't

I fear, transition can not work on display, if you want the image to disappear, consider using opacity combine with height and width.

```
.weight__calculations #body-mass-image {
  transition: all 1s linear;
  width: // the initial width;
  height: //the initial height;
  opacity: 1;
}

.weight__calculations #body-mass-image.body-mass-over {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

But if you actually need to use display none, then consider using setTimeout in JavaScript to display the image to none after 1 second, by then your your animation has finished with the opacity.

But again, you're trying to make a result_box appear and image to disappear on click with some transition implementation... Transition should not be used at this situation, but you need animation because transition needs action like "hover" before implementing, but animation implements on it's own... You will have to set up an appear and disappear css for both image and result_box:

example

```
. result_box_appearance{
   opacity: 0;
   height:0;
   width:0;
   animation: 1s linear;
   animation-name: result_box_appearance;
}


@keyframes result_box_appearance{
0%{
   opacity: 0;
   height:0;
   width:0;
}

100%{
   opacity: 1;
   height: 70px;
   width: 90px;
}

}
```

So when you click the button, you can now assign the second className to the result_box.

`result_box.className = "result_box result_box_appearance";`

and you will have to do the same to disappear for both result_box and image

Comment: But with this, the result doesnt change with the image. Please have a look at the code snippet. So basically I am trying to add animation while displayin none for image and displayin block to result__box

Comment: Look into it again, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using display block, you can use max-height: 0; and to display it use max-height: 999px if this the height is big enough for you.

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('show');

button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const image = document.getElementById('image');
  const text = document.getElementById('text');
  
  if (image.classList.contains('show')) {
    image.classList.remove('show');
    text.classList.add('show');
    return;
  }
  image.classList.add('show');
  text.classList.remove('show');
});
```

```css
.block {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}
.block.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="show">
  toggle
</button>
<div id="image" class="block show">
  <img src="https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ultimate-small-business-resource-coronavirus.png" alt="some title" />
</div>

<div id="text" class="block">
  some text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I am trying to do, display result__box instead of the image with animation. So if I set height to 0, it doesnt replace.

Comment: @magicbean Take a look again?

Comment: I am doing more or less the same things as you see in my code, but animation doesnt work properly. I tried everything

Comment: @magicbean as I've said before. Don't use display: none. Use max-height: 0 or max-width: 0